# Unable to run Spark in yarn-cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-spark-1.6

I'm trying to run spark job with YARN in cluster deploy mode.
I tried to run the simpliest spark-submit command only with jar path, class parameter and master yarn-cluster. However I still have the same error, which actually tells me nothing.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1506196351647_0032 finished with failed status
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1078)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1125)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

If anyone had the similar problem please let me know, I'm using spark 1.6, hadoop 2.6.

Comment: can you please specify the command, I mean the spark-submit

Comment: spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --class com.xx.datalake.xx /data/cma_app/lib/xx_bigdata.jar

Comment: the correct way is `spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --class com.xx.datalake.xx /data/cma_app/lib/xx_bigdata.jar`

Comment: I tried both commands, same error.

Comment: how did you solve this issue ?